# Android, multiDexEnabled = true --> not start Espresso tests (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: android-espresso

Android Studio 2.3.1.

I write my Espresso test in folder "androidTest" and it work fine.
Today I add new dependency in my build.gradle. As result I get error when try to start unit test:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevAndroidTest'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I fix this by (in build.gradle):

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled = true
  }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.21"
    androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6"
    androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"

    //WireMock
    androidTestCompile("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0") {
       exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
       exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
       exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'
       exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

But now the Espresso test can not run on Android 4.3. I get error:

> Running tests
>
> com.myproject.fragment.MyTest#myTestMethod com.myproject.android.dev.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
>       Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
>           Empty test suite.

I found solutions of problem:

1. If you use Android 5.0- (e.g. Android 4.3) then you **MUST** use Wiremock version **2.0.8-beta**

   androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.0.8-beta'
2. If you use Android 5.0+ you can you use any Wiremock version (e.g. 2.5.0)

`androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0'`

P.S. Maybe this is a Multidex issues.